# Transferring HTML5 documents to a web address

Tags: html, web

First of all I'm inexperienced with html5 and I know that's not a good excuse for my ignorance 
but I wondered..
How would you transfer an HTML5 file or replicate it on to a web address.
Assuming I had a website called www.websiteexample.com
I've researched but haven't seen much results that address the topic.
If what i'm saying is incorrect,feel free to correct my mistakes.

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
Hello world!
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to publish a website? Or save the html from an existing website?

Comment: publish a site. But I haven't had the an actual domain yet I just want to understand how to publish websites.

Comment: Please look into the difference between hosting and domain name. If you have purchased a domain name you don't automatically get the space (hosting) to place files. Those are two separate things. Usually a domain costs about $10-20 per year, whereas hosting costs $100-$200 per year.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what webserver you are running and how its configured.

In the simplest scenario, An `HTML5` file (or any HTML file) is usually a regular file on the server with an `.html` extension.

For example, if you have domain name `www.example.com`running on web server configured with default settings, it will most probably be serving the content from a directory such as `/var/www/example.com/` on the server.

When a user types `http://www.example.com/` into the browser the web server looks for an index or default html file to serve up as a web page.

The chances are the the first file it will look for, will be a file called `index.html`. That `index.html` in the above scenario, will be located at `/var/www/example.com/index.html` on the server.

If you wanted to create another page, its just a matter of finding the file and copying the file to a new name on the server.

So, If you logged into the server and copied the `index.html` file to `index-copy.html`, then you would be then able to access the new page at `http://www.example.com/index-copy.html`.

Most web site hosts won't give you full access to the file system, but may instead give you access to either;

1. An FTP login - In which case you will need a ftp program to upload your files to the server.
2. A web based file system, which you will be able to see the directory structure and most probably drag and drop files from your local computer to your web server and rename them etc.

The concept is still the same though, find the file and copy it to another file with a new name.